# Google Map not appearing in create-react-app component

Tags: google-maps, reactjs

I have a google map component that I know for a fact is rendering, however the map is not showing up. This is my code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

const google = window.google

class GoogleMaps extends Component {

  componentDidMount(){
    new google.maps.Map(this.refs.map, {
      zoom: 12,
      center: {
        lat: 37.773329,
        lng: -122.416416
      }
    })
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <div ref="map"/>
        <h1>map?</h1>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default GoogleMaps;
```

Comment: do you see any errors in the developer console ?

Comment: I fixed it, I needed to set a width and height. There is none set by default.

Comment: please provide that as an answer to this question and mark it as resolved. It maybe useful for others

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, I needed to set a width and height. There is none set by default.